# Java Stack Evaluation from TXT file

Tags: java, stack, equation, evaluation

In this assignment, I need to read a `.txt` file and determine if the expressions are correct or "Balanced". The first problem I got correct but for the second problem I am getting more output than I want. Here is the problem for #2:

> Write a stack-based algorithm that evaluates a post-fixed expression.  Your program needs to read its input from a file called “problem2.txt”.  This file contains one expression per line. 
>       For each expression output its value to the standard output. If an expression is ill-formed print “Ill-formed”.

The Problem2.txt is as follows:

```
3  2  +  5  6  8  2  /  +  +  *  1  + 
8 * 2  3 + + -  9 1 +
1  4  +  9  4  -  *  2  *
// For my output I need to get:
76
Ill-formed
50

// With my code I am getting:
76
Ill-formatted
Ill-formatted
Ill-formatted
10
50
// and I’m not sure why I’m getting extra ill-formatted and a 10 in there
```

Below is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.EmptyStackException;

public class Eval {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    //driver
        try (BufferedReader filereader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Problem1.txt"))) {
            while (true) {
                String line = filereader.readLine();
                if (line == null) {
                   break;
                }

                System.out.println(balancedP(line));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        try (BufferedReader filereader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Problem2.txt"))) {
            while (true) {
                String line = filereader2.readLine();
                if (line == null) {
                   break;
                }

                System.out.println(evaluatePostfix(line));
            }
        }
    }


    public static boolean balancedP (String s) {
        Stack<Character> stackEval  = new Stack<Character>();

        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

            char token = s.charAt(i);

            if(token == '[' || token == '(' || token == '{' ) {     
                stackEval.push(token);
            } else if(token == ']') {
                if(stackEval.isEmpty() || stackEval.pop() != '[') {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if(token == ')') {
                if(stackEval.isEmpty() || stackEval.pop() != '(') {
                    return false;
                }           
            } else if(token == '}') {
                if(stackEval.isEmpty() || stackEval.pop() != '{') {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return stackEval.isEmpty();
       }



    //problem 2 algo to evaluate a post-fixed expression
    static int evaluatePostfix(String exp) throws EmptyStackException
    { 
        Stack<Integer> stackEval2 = new Stack<>(); 

        for(int i = 0; i < exp.length(); i++) 
        { 
            char c = exp.charAt(i); 

            if(c == ' ') 
            continue; 

            else if(Character.isDigit(c)) { 
                int n = 0; 

                while(Character.isDigit(c)) { 
                   n = n*10 + (int)(c-'0'); 
                    i++; 
                    c = exp.charAt(i); 
                } 
                i--; 

                stackEval2.push(n); 
            } 

            else { 

                try {
                //if operand pops two values to do the calculation through the switch statement
                int val1 = stackEval2.pop(); 

                int val2 = stackEval2.pop(); 
                //operands in a switch to test and do the operator's function each value grabbed and tested
                switch(c) { 
                    case '+': 
                    stackEval2.push(val2 + val1); 
                    break; 

                    case '-': 
                    stackEval2.push(val2 - val1); 
                    break; 

                    case '/': 
                    stackEval2.push(val2 / val1); 
                    break; 

                    case '*': 
                    stackEval2.push(val2 * val1); 
                    break; 
                } 
                } catch (EmptyStackException e) {
                    System.out.println("Ill-formatted");
                }
            } 
        } 
        return stackEval2.pop();  
    } 
}
```

Comment: I think the first expression `3  2  +  5  6  8  2  /  +  +  *  1  +` is not valid postfix.  This would become, after the first addition, `5 5  6  8  2  /  +  +  *  1  +`, which makes no sense.

Comment: These are the expressions my teacher has given me and I cannot change them.  My Code still gives me the correct response that I am looking for. The problem with getting multiple ill-formatted I believe is in expression 2.

Comment: Well the second expression is certainly ill formatted, because a `*` appears with only one available operand on the stack.  I don't have an issue with your output for the second expression.

Comment: On my end I am getting 3 ill formats instead of only getting 1. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: You're getting multiple "ill-formed" messages and an unexpected result because you're continuing to try to evaluate the expression after you've determined it to be malformed.   Instead of printing a message in your `catch` clause, you need to `break;' out of the `for` loop and _then_ display the error.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am currently working out what you just commented and when I break out of the for loop the error message cannot be reached. Do I place my break right under my catch statement? or do I need to move the error message?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to have the output formatted how you want is to just put the `try-catch` block around where you are calling the `evaluatePostfix()` method (*make sure to delete the `try-catch` block that is inside the `evaluatePostfix()` method*):

```
System.out.println("\n");
try (BufferedReader filereader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Problem2.txt"))) {
    while (true) {
        String line = filereader2.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            break;
        }

        try {
            System.out.println(evaluatePostfix(line));
        } catch (EmptyStackException e) {
            System.out.println("Ill-formatted");
        }
    }
}
```

This way, when an exception occurs inside the `evaluatePostfix()` method, the method will throw the exception and the exception will be dealt with outside of the looping, thus, avoiding duplicate error messages and other unwanted effects.